# Accessing rails routes in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes

Can anyone explain how i can access the rails routes/names routes in javascript ?

The following are some of the things i tried 
http://github.com/jsierles/js_named_routes.

but no luck.

Comment: I also looked at http://tore.darell.no/pages/javascript_routes

Comment: do you want access to all routes in JavaScript as you would see with say `rake routes`?

Answer (score 44):

I was researching this question for a while and didn't found any implementation compatible with Rails 3.

So decided to write my own:

https://github.com/railsware/js-routes

Comment: This should be rolled into rails, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 24):

kishore I think this is the simpliest way, just call:

> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.*_path

So, if you have in your routes.rb, let's say:

> resources :users

then you want to call the index action from a javascript file, you do:

```
$.get('<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path %>', function(data){ ...
```

Take into account that the js file should have a .erb extension (or *.js.erb) so rails knows that must be preprocessed. Otherwise, the file will be served as is.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your requirement correctly you want Javascript code in your views to have access to the named routes. If so, then one simple way to do this is to render your Javascript code through a template (ERB, Haml, etc) and then to expand the routes something like the following:

**ERB**:

```
<script>

  $.get('<%= some_named_route_path %>', function(data) {

  });

</script>
```

**Haml**:

```
:javascript

  $.get('#{ some_named_route_path }', function(data) {

  });
```

UPDATE: Adding suggestions for `public/javascripts/` case

Accessing named routes from the public folder is a bit trickier but there at least 2 ways that come to mind, neither of which is entirely satisfactory but, one or either of which might suit your application

1. Create javascript templates in (say) `lib/javascripts` using ERB named like `'*.js.erb'` and a `rake` task to expand those templates into `public/javascript`s before deploying (say as a step in your Capistrano recipe for example). Downside of that is that your changes are not made available live on the site until the templates are expanded and you might not get the right syntax highlighting of your javascript with an `.erb` extension file
2. Create per-view javascript helper functions in a `content_for :head` block which expand the named routes and make those available to code from your public javascript files. If you're careful with namespacing and conventions this might work out well. The downside is that the code calling these javascript helpers is decoupled from the code that defines them which could be confusing for maintainers or prone to abuse.

In some view:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script>
    SomeNameSpace.helper_to_some_named_route = function() {
      return '%<= some_named_route_path %>
    };
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Then in `public/application.js` (say)

```
$.get(SomeNameSpace.helper_to_some_named_route(), function(data) {

});
```

Comment: Thank for your help. But if I want to access them in my public/javascript files , How can I access them.

Answer (score 3):

bjg really answered this, but I thought I'd extract the relevant part and amplify with an example.

You simply provide your view a string variable whose value is a named Rails path, and then use that value in the Javascript of your form.  An example that illustrates how a controller method can specify the path for another method, to be opened by the script on the press of a button:

File `config/routes.rb`:

```
...
resource :foo, :only => [:show, :reset]
...
match 'foo_reset_path' => 'foo#reset'
```

Commanding `rake routes` will now produce, among other output, this:

```
foo             GET  /foo(.:format)            foo#show
foo_reset_path       /foo_reset_path(.:format) foo#reset
```

`foo_reset_path` is what we're going to use here, but you can of course use this method with any named Rails path.

File `app/controllers/foo_controller.rb`:

```
...
def show
  @reset_path = "foo_reset_path" # simply the string you'd use in the
                                 # Rails code for opening the path
  ...
end
...
def reset
  ... # reset some variables to their default values
  redirect_to foo_path # causes the show method to be called, and the HTML
                       # page to be redisplayed
end
```

File `app/views/foo/show.html.erb`:

```
...
<input type="hidden" id="reset_path" name="reset_path" value="<%= @reset_path %>">
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    /* Hang functionality on the "Reset form" button. */
    $('#reset_button').click(function () {
        var reset_path = $('#reset_path').val();
        window.open(reset_path, "_self")
    });
    ...
})
</script>
```

I'm using JQuery here, but the basic idea should be clear.  The script adds a hook to the button element whose id is `reset_button`, so that clicking on the button causes the `reset` method of `foo_controller` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

What I did based on Teemu's great answer:

In your controller:

```
def show
  @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @section}
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="section_path" data-path="<%= @section.id %>" name="section_path" value="foo">
```

In your js:

```
var id = $('#section_path').attr('data-path');

$.ajax({
    url:'/sections/'+ id +'.json',
    type:"GET",
    success: function (data){
        console.info(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status){
        console.info(xhr.error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JS pipeline that supports `import` (ES6 + [`webpacker`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker)), you might want to check out [`js_from_routes`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes), a code-generation library that works seamlessly with Rails reloader.

For each endpoint that you'd like to access from JS, it will [generate a method](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/requests/VideoClipsRequests.js#L32-L33) that can help you [build a URL](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/requests/VideoClipsRequests.js#L8-L9) or make a request.

```rb
resources :video_clips, only: [:update], export: true
```

By using it [in combination](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/services/ApiService.js#L32) with [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), these generated helpers can be convenient and easy to use:

```js
import VideoClipsRequests from '@requests/VideoClipsRequests'

VideoClipsRequests.update({ data: video })
  .then(onVideoUpdate)
```

Have in mind that you can adjust the generated code by providing a **custom** template, so it can adapt to any technology you are using, even plain jQuery.

Benefits:

- No need to manually specify the URL, preventing mistakes and saving development time.
- If an action is renamed or removed, the helper ceases to exist, which causes an error that is easier to detect than a 404.

Answer (score -1):

See http://tore.darell.no/pages/javascript_routes:

> JavascriptRoutes converts your Rails routes into JavaScript. You can then access (generate) them in the browser (or any other JS environment). It supports both normal and named routes, and creates helper functions for the latter.

**Update**: It looks as though someone has forked this if you prefer jQuery: https://github.com/ajnsit/javascript_routes

Answer (score -2):

1. gem install the "angular_rails_templates"
2. Create a file called angular_rails_templates.rb in the config/initializers folder
3. copy following code in the file and restart server.  (including "module CustomERBEngine" for it cannot be added to code block by 4 space)

`module CustomERBEngine`

```
class ERBTemplate < Tilt::ERBTemplate

def evaluate(scope, locals, &block)
  scope.class_eval do
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    include Rails.application.routes.mounted_helpers
    include ActionView::Helpers
   end
      super
    end
  end
end

Tilt.register CustomERBEngine::ERBTemplate, '.erb'
```