# My ajax call doesn't understand Rails routes path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a problem with Rails and Ajax (I'm a beginner).

I have a very large form, and inside this form I have some buttons.

I need to attach an ajax call on these buttons: when i click I need to pass some parameters to the controller and I must then save this parameters in my model.

I create the route and the controller method, but my script doesn't recognize the rails route path.

```
$("#crop_square").click (e) ->
    $.ajax
      url: save_crop_data_admin_article_path
      type: "POST"
      data: "test"
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->


      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->


    #if fails      
    e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Ajax, cannot understand rails path. Better you replace it with fullpath manually.

Comment: can you paste the output of "rake routes" in your app path?

Comment: [Accessing rails routes in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257818/accessing-rails-routes-in-javascript).

Comment: You can pass url as relative path or if you have more pathes, probably  better to use the gem https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/